# QuantLib Error: “QuantLib::Handle<QuantLib::TermStructure>” cannot convert to “const QuantLib::Handle<QuantLib::YieldTermStructure> &”

Tags: c++, quantlib

I'm working with QuantLib 1.19 in C++. When I try to pass a TermStructure Handle to create a new IborIndex, I get the error in the subject. My code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace QuantLib;

    Date today(21, Apr, 2021);
    std::string familyName("TestTest");
    Period tenor(1, Years);
    Natural settlementDays(0);
    USDCurrency usd;
    Currency currency(usd);
    TARGET target;
    BusinessDayConvention convention(ModifiedFollowing);
    bool endOfMonth(true);
    Actual365Fixed dayCounter;

    ext::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure> crv(new FlatForward(today, 0.03, dayCounter));
    Handle<TermStructure> crv_handle(crv);

    IborIndex crv_index(familyName, tenor, settlementDays, currency, target, convention, endOfMonth, dayCounter, crv_handle);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm checking the definition of IborIndex in 1.19, which is this:

```
    class IborIndex : public InterestRateIndex {
      public:
        IborIndex(const std::string& familyName,
                  const Period& tenor,
                  Natural settlementDays,
                  const Currency& currency,
                  const Calendar& fixingCalendar,
                  BusinessDayConvention convention,
                  bool endOfMonth,
                  const DayCounter& dayCounter,
                  const Handle<YieldTermStructure>& h =
                                    Handle<YieldTermStructure>());
```

But in the newest version 1.22, it's removed const in the termstructure handle parameter:

```
    class IborIndex : public InterestRateIndex {
      public:
        IborIndex(const std::string& familyName,
                  const Period& tenor,
                  Natural settlementDays,
                  const Currency& currency,
                  const Calendar& fixingCalendar,
                  BusinessDayConvention convention,
                  bool endOfMonth,
                  const DayCounter& dayCounter,
                  Handle<YieldTermStructure> h = Handle<YieldTermStructure>());
```

I'm new to C++. So maybe it's really a question of basic C++. But could you please help me understand the reason I'm having this error in 1.19? And why it's now changed in 1.22?

Much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor parameter specifically requires you to pass a `Handle<YieldTermStructure>`.

You however are passing a `Handle<TermStructure>` which is an incompatible type and that is why you get the error.

I don't know the library but I expect you can correct it by declaring

```
Handle<YieldTermStructure> crv_handle(crv);
```

The change that happened in 1.22 is unrelated. The parameter passing method for that parameter has changed from *by-constant-reference* to *by-value*. You would still get the same error.

Comment: Ahha. I feel embrassed. Obviously a careless mistake from a new C++ programmer.  Thank you so much!